# Inline a ps aux while loop

Tags: bash, shell

How would I do the following as a one-line entry in the bash prompt:

```
$ while true do [ps aux|grep python && sleep 1]
```

Basically, I'd like to run a `while` loop without having to create a file for it, but just by copy-pasting the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're having basic syntax issues. Note the the square bracket, `[`, is a *command*, not a container for other expressions (like squiggly or round brackets).

```
while sleep 1; do ps aux|grep python; done
```

Or if you want to be fancier:

```
while sleep 1; do ps aux|grep '[p]ython'; done
```

to avoid matching your `grep` process.